# How can PrincipalContext / UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity() use a read-only domain controller?

Tags: .net, active-directory, domaincontroller

Active Directory (AD DS) has a concept of 'read-only domain controllers' (RODC).  Probably for backward compatibility, the default is that read-only domain controllers are ignored: you have to specify explicitly that you allow connecting to a read-only domain controller.

In our C# code we see that at two places.  One is when creating a new [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx): there the problem is easily solved by setting the [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx#enumerationSection) flag, which allows an RODC to be used.

**My question** is how to achieve the same thing for code like the following, which uses classes from the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                                                      ctx,
                                                      IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                      ...))
{
    // ...
}
```

since we observed that this code ignores any read-only domain controllers.

(Note that the above is exactly the same question as posted at the [MSDN "Visual C# General" forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/csharpgeneral/threads) in a thread entitled ["Issue connecting to read-only domain controller (RODC) from C# application through System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/csharpgeneral/thread/33c62c50-e7eb-4241-bad6-260c58f62544).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what happened was this was over looked as this functionality doesn't exist.  If it wasn't over looked then it was intentional, as a RODC wouldn't allow you to do many of the methods that exist on a `UserPrincipal` (eg ChangePassword, Delete, etc).  I would imagine that to solve this problem, Microsoft would have to create a new `ReadOnlyUserPrincipal`.  More importantly, why would it make sense to instantiate anything in the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace as read only as the namespace appears to be more than a read only *service* (for lack of a better term), unless a read-only version didn't exist (which is the case).  Hence, using a non-read only *sevice* and pointing it to a read only source doesn't work.

Comment: OK, thanks for this "it's not possible" answer.  All we're trying to do in this specific code is to get the UPN given a user's sAMAccountName, which does not require write access.  I'm assuming this means we should be doing that through a `DirectoryEntry` instead?  That is what I'm going to try, anyway.